# Why do I get NameError: name 'self' is not defined?

Tags: python

When I am trying to run this python code:

```
def convertProjection(self,x,y,from_crs,to_crs):
    crsSrc = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(from_crs)
    crsDest = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(to_crs)
    xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(crsSrc, crsDest)
    pt = xform.transform(QgsPoint(x,y))
    return pt.x, pt.y

# Remove the "EPSG:" part

from_crs = 3857
to_crs = 4326
x = -11705274.6374
y = 4826473.6922
lon, lat = self.convertProjection(x,y,from_crs,to_crs)
```

this error occurrs:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/jithin/PycharmProjects/PythonTests/XYTOLatLong_Conversion.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jithin/PycharmProjects/PythonTests/XYTOLatLong_Conversion.py", line 36, in <module>
    lon, lat = self.convertProjection(x,y,from_crs,to_crs)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Any help is appreciated.... Thanks...

Comment: The error message pretty much says it. You are referring to `self` which is not defined. It looks like you have ripped out the function from a class. As the function does not seem to reference self, you can remove it from the parameter list, and call it as a regular function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you copied that code from a class.

In Python, by convention (PEP 8), "self" refers to the current instance of an object. If your code is outside of a class, self will not be defined, as there is no instance.

You should change

```
def convertProjection(self,x,y,from_crs,to_crs):
```

to

```
def convertProjection(x,y,from_crs,to_crs):
```

and then call the function without "self.".

Comment: "In Python, self refers to the current instance of an object." It should be noted that that's only a convention, not enforced by the language. "If your code is outside of a class, self will not be defined, as there is no instance." That's not technically true. In OP's code `convertProjection` is defined outside of a class, but `self` *is* defined inside that function because `convertProjection` takes a parameter named `self`. Similarly one could put `self = 42` anywhere in the code and `self` would then be defined in that scope.

Comment: You are right, but in this context, it looks like OP took the code from a class. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`convertProjection` is a regular function defined outside a class, so you should not use it as a bound method.

Change:

```
def convertProjection(self,x,y,from_crs,to_crs):
```

to:

```
def convertProjection(x,y,from_crs,to_crs):
```

and change:

```
lon, lat = self.convertProjection(x,y,from_crs,to_crs)
```

to

```
lon, lat = convertProjection(x,y,from_crs,to_crs)
```

Comment: /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/jithin/PycharmProjects/PythonTests/XYTOLatLong_Conversion.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jithin/PycharmProjects/PythonTests/XYTOLatLong_Conversion.py", line 36, in <module>
    lon, lat = convertProjection(x,y,from_crs,to_crs)
  File "/home/jithin/PycharmProjects/PythonTests/XYTOLatLong_Conversion.py", line 24, in convertProjection
    crsSrc = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(from_crs)
NameError: name 'QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem' is not defined